# Python websocket asyncio using the same connection more than once

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, json-rpc

Hi all I am hoping someone here can help me with the jsonrpcclient using websockets. I am very new to using websockets and have to use jsonrpc for a project. I have searched the site but unfortunately I was unable to find the answer.

Below is the sample code from the documention which I can get working. But I wish to create the websockets.connect then use it with multiple responses.

**【Base Code】**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from jsonrpcclient.clients.websockets_client import WebSocketsClient


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:5000") as ws:
        response = await WebSocketsClient(ws).request("ping")
    print(response.data.result)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**【What I Want】**

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from jsonrpcclient.clients.websockets_client import WebSocketsClient


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:5000") as ws:
        response = await WebSocketsClient(ws).request("ping")
        print(response.data.result)

        response2 = await WebSocketsClient(ws).request("donkey")
        print(response2.data.result)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Additional Question: Is it possible to set the client up like a server so it is always running and listing and if it gets a command from another script that it will call the main function?

Thank you in advance for any help!

> https://jsonrpcclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#websockets

OS: Windows

Python: 3.8

Except Error when running code similar to 'What I want': code = 1000 (OK) No reason

---

**EDIT**

After trial and error and lots of Googling it seems you just have to have the server running in a while loop to process multiple requests in a row like I am after.

However if someone finds out a way to do this with out putting the server in a while loop I would love to hear how.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried creating a single client for both requests, [like this](https://pastebin.com/8sxG4mnP)?

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately it is the same problem. It seems I have to put the listening sever in a while loop to remain open for the second response. Ideally I would like to find a way to do it just on the client side if possible.